# How can i split a column in a csv file to two columns?

Tags: pandas, csv, split

I am trying to take some data from a csv file that has a timestamp and a value in the same cell and is split with a comma.

The data set looks like this:

```
date,reactive
2020-01-01 00:00:00,25534.1396484375
```

Ive tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_file = "Reaktiv_syntetisk_jan2022.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

df[['Timestamp', "reacitve"]] = df['date,reactive'].astype(str).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

This is what i tried but here i just get:
`KeyError: 'date,reactive'`

If i change the header in the csv file to "date reactive" and write:

```
df[['Timestamp', "reacitve"]] = df['date,reactive'].astype(str).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

i get the message:
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to read the csv as 2 columns directly. `pd.read_csv(csv_file)` should give you 2 columns if the format is really as shown.

Comment: How can i just access the timestamp data if they are separated already?

Comment: just `df['date']`

Comment: Have you tried to actually check what is `df`? `print(df)` / `print(df['date'])`